# Why am I getting NZEC error on an online judge?

Tags: java

The code I wrote works fine everywhere on the internet. But on Codechef, it shows an NZEC error. I don't understand why. I've tried many test cases and I'm getting the expected output on my computer or anywhere online. Please help.
Below is my source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class abc{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


                int t = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    int scount=0,mcount=0;

    while(t!=0)
    {

    scount=0;
    mcount=0;

    String str=sc.next();


    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {

        if(str.charAt(i)=='m')
            {
                mcount++;
                if(i==0)
                    {
                        if(str.charAt(1)=='s')
                        scount--;
                    }
                else if(i==(str.length()-1))
                    {
                        if(str.charAt(i-1)=='s')
                        scount--;
                    }
                else 
                    if(str.charAt(i-1)=='s')
                    scount--;
                else 
                    if (str.charAt(i+1)=='s')
                    scount--;

            }
        else if(str.charAt(i)=='s')
            scount++;

    }


    if(scount==mcount)
        System.out.println("tie");
    else if(scount>mcount)
        System.out.println("snakes");
    else
        System.out.println("mongooses");

    t--;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What does the error say exactly?

Comment: It simply says "Runtime error": NZEC(Non Zero Exit code)

Comment: Your algorithm is flawed. According to the problem description if you input "msmmssss" the result should be "tie" (since no more than two snakes can be eaten), but your code will output "mongooses".

Comment: @ThomasKläger Yupp. Got it. I had to add the constraints when a snake is already eaten by the left mongoose, it cannot be eaten by the right one. Thanks for help.